# Word-wrap break word in paragraph in a table

Tags: css, html-table, word-wrap

I have got a simple table like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td id="col1"><p>test1</p></td>
   <td id="col2">
        <p>testtestetst@test.com</p>
        <p>abcd@efg.com</p>
        <p>testtesttesttest@gmail.comasdfdsasadfsadfsadfasdf</p>
   </td>
   <td id="col3"><p>10 April 2010 4:33 PM</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And some CSS:

```
table{
  width: 300px;
}

#col1{
    width: 100px;
}

#col2{
    width: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}

#col3{
    width: 100px;
}

p{
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

And a fiddle of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/ypMQX/

I have fixed the width of the table and each column. I have also set `word-wrap` to `break-word` for all paragraph elements. I then set a max width to `#col2`. Why is it that column 2 is allow to expand so much without wrapping even though I have set it to `break-word`?

I would like all my columns to have a fixed width, and then have the content inside wrap. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What browser you're testing on ? I'm on firefox and this is what I see

[image]

Anyway this breaks on IE, you can add another selector for paragraph along with your `#col2` like:

```
#col2, #col2 p {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was seeing problems with the fiddle in IE. However, in my project (which is a lot more complicated), I am seeing the issue in FF as well. However, defining a width for `p` seems to have fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add 100px width to <p> tag. You dont need to add 100px width to table columns.

Here is the required css:

```
table{
  width: 300px;
}


p{
 word-wrap: break-word;
 width: 100px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QNwtj/4/